# PsShutdown needs admin rights when setting t neq to 0

Tags: windows-10, batch, non-admin

In a batch script on Windows 10 using PsShutdown to sleep my PC I noticed that PsShutdown needs admin rights if setting -t to everything except 0. You get an "Access is denied" message if running the script unelevated. This is also true for leaving -t out completely (default t=20). My question: Is this normal behavior for PsShutdown, and if so, is it possible to change?

Works without elevation:

```
PsShutdown -d -t 0
```

Needs elevation:

```
PsShutdown -d -t 120
PsShutdown -d
```

Comment: Found a workaround by using cmd commands TIMEOUT or PING, which both work unelevated, but using the built in time delay in PsShutdown would be more elegant.

Comment: I have to assume that the ability to message other users on the box is the reason for the admin requirement. MS locked down `net send` a decade or so ago.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Thanks for your info.